# Jmeter : How to extract first element from json array

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to extract first element from a json array. Below mentioned is json array

```
   [
    {
        "cohortDefinition": {
            "Key": 1151,
            "id": 1798,
            "srcId": "3526",
            "pcKey": -1,
            "userName": "CHROME_USER",
            "name": "JMeter2017-01-06-1483749546167",
            "Type": "SUBJECT",
            "tool": "CB",
            "count": 32757,
            "extractionStatus": "",
            "dateCreated": "2017-05-10T17:48:45Z"
        },
        "datasource": {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "health",
            "subjectCount": 116352
        },
        "project": {
            "id": 747,
            "name": "Jmeter Project"
        }
    },
    {
        "cohortDefinition": {
            "Key": 1150,
            "id": 1796,
            "srcId": "3525",
            "pcKey": -1,
            "userName": "CHROME_USER",
            "name": "JMeter2016-10-27-1477620919644",
            "Type": "SUBJECT",
            "tool": "CB",
            "count": 32757,
            "extractionStatus": "",
            "dateCreated": "2017-05-10T16:57:11Z"
        },
        "datasource": {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "health",
            "subjectCount": 116352
        },
        "project": {
            "id": 747,
            "name": "Jmeter Project"
        }
    }
]
```

From above json i would like to extract first value ie. srcId": "3526". 
I tried doing following expression in Jmeter extractor

```
$..cohortDefinition.srcId[1]
```

However it is not working. If anyone know how to do this please do let me know.

Comment: Use `$..cohortDefinition.srcId` in the `JSON Path Extractor`. `myVar_1` will have the first `srcId`.

Comment: I tried that option. This results in 3526 and 3525

Comment: Yes. You need to use `myVar_1` in your test plan which will retrieve first `srcId`.

Comment: Please check this image http://imgur.com/a/rzA8p and http://imgur.com/a/8rFfd

Comment: This worked. Thanks a lot Naveen

Comment: Posting my answer. Please accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After JMeter 3.0, you can use [JSON Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor), see:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/47043204/460802

**Before JMeter 3.0:**

Please follow the below steps to retrieve `srcId`.

1. Add a `JSON Path Extractor` to your request and configure below values.

> Destination Variable Name - `myVar`
>
> JSON Path Expression - `$..cohortDefinition.srcId` - this will extract all the srcIDs from the JSON.
>
> Default Value - `Not Found` or `Err`

[image: JSON Path Config]

2. Add a `Debug Sampler` and `View Results Tree` to your test plan.
3. Save it and execute.
4. In `Debug Sampler`, you can view all the `srcId` as shown below.

[image: Output]

> You can now use `myVar_1` and `myVar_2` in your test plan
>   using `${myVar_1}` `${myVar_2}`

Answer (score 1):

No need for Plugin, JMeter has a [JSON Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) that will provide this feature:

[image: JSON Extractor configuration]

Notice:

> JSON Path Expression is: $..cohortDefinition.srcId
>
> Match No : 1